# Is it possible to create an audio recorder in Javascript?

Tags: microphone

I would like to create a javascript app that record the microphone input and saves it to a file, in javascript, without flash and without java
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible, although if you want to save the file to the client's local file system it will only work in Chromium/Chrome (you will need to use the [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API), which has since been abandoned by other browser vendors).

You'll need to leverage the Web Audio and WebRTC APIs. Here's a tutorial that shows the basics: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/